# showing password in Qt

Tags: qt

I am developing a Qt program.at first of it it has a login page.for entering the password in a `QLineEdit` when you enter the password it shows some dots as if it is hidden.I made a `QCheckBox` for showing password.but I don't know how to write it's `SLOT` that when it is checked the password shown.is there any Qt function?what should I do?

Comment: this may help you http://programmingexamples.wikidot.com/qt-signals-and-slots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create handler of your QCheckBox toggle event where you have to write a something looks like:

```
yourLineEdit->setEchoMode(yourCheckBox->checkState() == Qt::Checked ? QLineEdit::Normal : QLineEdit::Password );
```

Comment: It does't work?!!!!the password just are shown by dots and by checking th e checkbox it isn't changed?!

Comment: I just copied your code and changed the parameter names.it compiles with no problem but does't give the result I want.should'nt I write any slot and signal?

Comment: have you connected the toggle signal of your QCheckBox with the just written handler of your form?

Comment: You create a slot, that slot you connect to the stateChanged signal: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcheckbox.html#stateChanged (or toggled signal - make sure that you create a slot with compatible type of parameters to the signal you choose to use) and inside that slot you use that code (or modify that line to use the bool that comes as toggled parameter)

Answer (score 1):

See QLineEdit's [EchoMode](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html#EchoMode-enum) and set it to the option that best fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Other form.

#Create event

self.nameCheckbox.clicked.connect(self.click)

#Create def

def click(self):
if(self.nameCheckbox.isChecked()):
self.txtname.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Normal)

else:
self.txtname.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)